# AttributeError in list.sort().reverse() in python3

Tags: python-3.x, reverse, nonetype

can anyone explain why is that error shown in the code below?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [5, 6, 2, 7, 9]
    a.sort().reverse()
    print(a)
```

the error shown is given below:

```
File "first.py", line 3, in <module>
a.sort().reverse()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reverse'
```

Comment: Because [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) returns `None`, it sorts the list *in-place*. The Python standard library generally doesn't go for fluent interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort returns `None`. It is in place. You can do this in two steps as the other answer shows or pass the reverse argument to sort.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [5, 6, 2, 7, 9]
    a.sort(reverse=True)
```